# Ionic slide box pager used with ng-repeat causing issues

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The slide pager is doubling when I navigate from other pages.
Consider I have 2 slides coming from the api, there will be 2 pagers for the same. If I navigate through other page and come back to the page with the slides, I get 4 slide pager.

Comment: <div ng-if="bannerImages.length">
            <ion-slide-box ng-show="showBanner" delegate-handle="b2bMainSlider" show-pager="true" does-continue="true" auto-play="true">
                <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in bannerImages" ng-click="bannerSearch(img.store_id, img.banner_name)" class="b2b-banner">
                    <img ng-src="{{img.image_url}}" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

It's known `ion-slide-box` bug with two slides as you can see here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2336. You can try their new slide-box element

```
<ion-slides options="options">
  <ion-slide-page>
  </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```